# how to store name-value pairs in a Coldfusion array/object?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, coldfusion, multidimensional-array

Say I have a list of error messages like so:

```
fieldname    message
--------------------
zip          "please enter your zip code"
city         "please enter your city"
...
```

I need to store these name-value pairs in a Coldfusion**8** array/object to make them accessible to a client-side validation function (Jquery).

In Jquery I'm referencing error messages by id, so I need to store both.

What's the equivalent to this Jquery:

```
 var onErr = [ ["zip","please enter your zip code"], ["city", "please enter your city"]  ]
```

in Coldfusion?

I want to do something like this:

```
<cfset onErr = createObject("component","errorMsg.cfc")>
```

and in *errorMsg.cfc*:

```
<cfset onErr.zip = "please enter your zip code">
<cfset onErr.city = "please enter your city">
...
// then serialize this for pickup by Jquery validation handler
```

but not sure if this the best and most handy solution. I also looked at array, but there I can only store ID or message, can I? How about multidimensional arrays?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all help. Finally fiddled my way through (to the next obstacle :-).

Here is how it works (= I can JSONserialize to object and parse in Jquery):

```
<cfset allErrMsgs=ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset allErrMsgs[1][1] = "firma">
<cfset allErrMsgs[1][2] = tx_validate_firma>
<cfset allErrMsgs[2][1] = "re_firma">
<cfset allErrMsgs[2][2] = tx_validate_firma>
...
```

So whenever I get new error message, I only have to append them here in my error log. I create this log as a component on Session Start and whenever a user changes languages:

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an array of structures (map or object in other languages):

```
 var onErr = [ {"zip":"please enter your zip code"}, {"city":"please enter your city"}  ]
```

For serialization use serializeJSON() like so:

```
serializeJSON(onErr)
```

Or, if you are doing this by remote access to a function set returnformat="json"

Comment: hm. Coldfusion doesn't like []. Is this valid CF-syntax I can use in a Coldfusion.cfc file?

Comment: If < CF8 you'll need to use a lot of arrayNew(), structNew(), arrayAppend() and structAppend()'s

Comment: @frequent that might have been because of there where commas in the structure statements not = sign.

Comment: @MikeCauser The {} and [] shortcuts where added in CF8. Nesting might not have worked until 8.0.1 or even 9 though.

Comment: I found it out in the meantime. Hold up. Posting how I did it.

Comment: It might also be the "=" signs instead of ":" (fixed)